# Render raster from vector tiles in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) using Tileserver GL

Tags: tiles, wgs84, vector-tiles, openmaptiles, tileserver-gl

I have vector tiles that are in the WGS84 CRS (EPSG:4326). I can confirm that they are in WGS84 because on a Web Mercator basemap ([pg_tileserv](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_tileserv) preview) they display in Svalbard (should be in Austria):

[image: pg_tileserv function preview showing wgs84 vector tiles on a web mercator basemap]

When I load them in Tileserver GL using the following `style.json`, they do show up:

```json
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "Demo",
  "metadata": {
    "maputnik:license": "https://github.com/maputnik/osm-liberty/blob/gh-pages/LICENSE.md",
    "maputnik:renderer": "mbgljs",
    "openmaptiles:version": "3.x"
  },
  "sources": {
    "public-parcels": {
      "type": "vector",
      "tiles": [
        "localhost:8888/public.declarations_4326/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
      ],
      "minZoom": 0,
      "maxZoom": 14
    }
  },
  "sprite": "https://maputnik.github.io/osm-liberty/sprites/osm-liberty",
  "glyphs": "https://api.maptiler.com/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf?key={key}",
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "public-parcels",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "public-parcels",
      "source-layer": "public.declarations_4326",
      "paint": {"fill-color": "rgba(41, 99, 39, 1)"}
    }
  ],
  "id": "demo"
}
```

[image: vector tiles in Tileserver GL]

When I try to render the tiles as rasters (requesting the `?raster` endpoint), nothing shows up. I can confirm that the same configuration works for raster rendering web mercator tiles.

[image: raster rendering in Tileserver GL (blank page)]

Has anyone successfully rendered WGS84 raster tiles from vector tiles in Tileserver GL?